# Are there any tools for developing OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, shader

I am working on developing an iPad application. I need to use OpenGL ES 2.0 so that I can use custom shaders in my project. I am looking for a tool similar to the "Shader Builder" in OSX that works with OpenGL ES. Does such a tool exist?

I have tried using Shader Builder some.  It is nice, but it uses the non-ES version of OpenGL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ESSL is more or less a subset of GLSL x, using Shader Builder in OSX is a fairly good way to develop your shaders. The only difference would be for precision settings, but you will not get a proper result for that until you actually try it on a system.

There are solutions out there - malideveloper.com has a Eclipse plugin for shader development - but that is for Linux/Windows.

So, my answer is:

Use an `#ifdef SHADER_API_OGLES20` for precision
Try not to too use too weird builtin functions
Dump the compiler log when developing

Comment: I have had some luck using Shader Builder.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I wish there were better tools!

Answer (score 3):

you could use Typhoon Labs Shader Designer
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/tools/ShaderDesigner/

or glslDevil
http://cumbia.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/glsldevil/

also, you could check out this thread [Tools for GLSL editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593274/tools-for-glsl-editing)